# Brownian Motion in Confined space, any results?

Tags: geometry, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

I am searching for work regarding Brownian motion in a confined space, like a sphere or a cylinder, where the wall will serve as reflection boundary. I am wondering if it is possible to derive results such as the mean square displacement under such or similar constraint? I have been searching google for a while but did not get specific result. Any suggestion or recommendation will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the wall on a sphere? Do you mean a ball instead?

Comment: Yes, basically the Brownian particle is confined in a closed space. I am looking for any existing results regardless of the geometry of the space or the boundary condition.

Comment: The probability distribution is described by a harmonic function w/Neumann boundary condition?

Comment: I think you could look for "brownian motion on a riemaniann manifold". Most results will probably be with riemaniann manifold without boundary though.

Comment: Reflected Brownian motion: https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/Spring11/topics16.pdf